# How to use Arithmetic Operators in yii2 select query using model name?

Tags: postgresql, yii2

My table:-
account

```
| id | total_due | balance_amount |
| -- | --------- | -------------  |
|  1 | 200       | 100            |
|  2 | 400       | 50             |
```

I want to find the paid amount from the account table.
My model is Account.

postgres query for finding padi amount is

```
$query = "SELECT total_due - balance_amount as paid from account order by total_due - balance_amount desc";
```

My Yii code for above query is

```
Account::find()->select(['total_due - balance_amount as paid'])->orderBy(['total_due - balance_amount'] => SORT_DESC])->all();
```

it showing the error

> column "total_due - balance_amount" does not exist

Answer (score 0):

```
 Account::find()->select(['total_due - balance_amount as paid'])->orderBy(['paid' => SORT_DESC])->all()
```